# How to attach a Port shape to a class shape?

Tags: uml, draw.io, sysml

I am using the UML 2.5 shapes/connectors of draw.io to create diagrams and I came across the problem that I cannot attach a Port shape to a given class shape at any connection point. Draw.io seems to insist in using some connection between shapes using the connection points.

So how to attach a shape to a connection point of another shape?